# Error trying to add .jpg at the end of filename in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have an attribute in a table that goes `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....`. Right now, I'm trying to add .jpg to the file name. That is, it should be `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg,...`.

I tried using that command:

```
UPDATE tbl_items set filename = CAST(itemID AS char(10)) + '.jpg'
```

I'm getting this error

> 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '.jpg'

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `filename` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plus operator isn't valid in MySQL for string concatenation.  Instead, try using [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE tbl_items
SET filename = CONCAT(CAST(itemID AS CHAR(10)), '.jpg')
```

Your current error is probably arising because MySQL assumes you are trying to do arithmetic with either side of the plus operator.

Comment: Always thought the '+' was to do concatenation. It works now

Comment: @ElDj The plus operator [works in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql), but not in MySQL.